# Doctrine in Symfony3 invalid mapping file

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I just createt a Bundle FIRM/ComCollectBundle (with the name FirmComCollectBundle). Then I created a File src/FIRM/ComCollectBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/ForumUser.orm.yml with this content:

```
FIRMComCollectBundle\Entity\ForumUser:
  type: entity
  table: forum_users
  repositoryClass: FIRM\ComCollectBundle\Entity\ForumUserRepository
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 30
```

when I now try to use the console to create entities

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities FIRM\CommCollectBundle\ForumUser
```

I get this error:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]                       
  Invalid mapping file 'FIRM.ComCollectBundle.Entity.ForumUser.orm.yml' for cl  
  ass 'FIRM\ComCollectBundle\Entity\ForumUser'.
```

The same error (about ForumUser) even appears when I try to generate entities for another bundle (AppBundle)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that the `length: 30` was the problem, that has to be `length: '30'`